# Why is debugging Qt 5.3 on Windows much slower than on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I am using Qt 5.3 on Windows 8.1 64 bit and Ubuntu 14.04. Compared to Ubuntu, debugging on Windows takes ages.

Why is there such a huge difference? Do I need to set up anything special on Windows?

Comment: May be that's because you have set Symbol Server. Try to disable it and see the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely you're having this behaviour because your debugger can't find the debugging symbols for Windows-internal libraries. By default, they are not part of your Windows Installation or Qt Creator.
There are two ways to obtain them:

1. If you are behind a fast internet connection: Set up a symbol server from where symbols can be loaded on demand: http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-debugger-engines.html#setting-the-symbol-server-in-windows
2. Otherwise: Download the Debugging Symbols for Windows (usually part of the Windows SDK) from the Microsoft Homepage and configure your debugger to use the symbols from there. Usually you just specify a cache directory as in step 1 and install the symbols to that very folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging win32 code under x64 then there is a big chance you are doing it with x64 version of CDB, which CAN debug x86 binaries, but does it awfully slow.

The solution is to install Debugging Tools For Windows (from Windows SDK) and switch your debugger to the correct version. In this case - x86. The debugger will instantly become highly responsive.